# Modifying LESS variables not working for in-page <style> tag containing LESS code

Tags: javascript, less

Using the latest version of LESS (1.5.1), when I try to modify a LESS variable that's defined in a `<style>` tag in JS by calling `less.modifyVars()`, the variable doesn't get updated.

Example:

```
<style type="text/less">
@bgColor: red;
#box {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: @bgColor;
}
</style>

<div id="box"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="less-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#box").hover(
        function(){
            less.modifyVars({'@bgColor': 'blue'});
        },
        function(){
            less.modifyVars({'@bgColor': 'red'});
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

If the code in the `<style>` tag is put into an external LESS stylesheet and referenced via a `<link>` tag, then the LESS variable will get updated.

Any ideas why?  Is this a bug with LESS?

Thanks.

Comment: Avoid the whole mess by not using LESS client-side.

Comment: There are far better ways to change a background color on hover.

Comment: @ScottS:  Yes, for sure, but the above code is just an example to illustrate the issue I had when trying out LESS and changing variables.

Comment: I was hoping it was just a test case.

Answer (score 2):

### A Bug

[Here is the current thread that reports it](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1599). It was thought fixed, but reopened two months ago for LESS 1.5 because it was not, in fact, updating variables in `<style>` elements.